# blade file : $meeting is undefined

Tags: php, laravel

Whenever I visit the `add-meeting` URL, I receive an error message stating that `$meeting is undefined`. However, when I attempt to edit a meeting, everything works as expected. I am using the same blade file for both creating and updating meetings. Can you explain why this error is occurring?

Here is `MeetingController`:

```
public function add_meeting()
{
    $customers = Customer::all();
    $projects = Project::all();
    
    return view('admin.meeting.add-meeting', get_defined_vars());
}
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'meeting_scedule' => 'required',
        'meeting_user_id' => 'required',
        'project_id' => 'required',
        'agenda' => 'required',
    ]);

    if ($request->id) {

        $input['meeting_scedule'] = $request->meeting_scedule;
        $input['meeting_user_id'] = $request->meeting_user_id;
        $input['project_id'] = $request->project_id;
        $input['agenda'] = $request->agenda;

        $meeting = Meeting::where('id', $request->id)->update($input);
        return back()->with('success', 'Updated Successfully!');

    } else {
        $new['meeting_scedule'] = $request->meeting_scedule;
        $new['meeting_user_id'] = $request->meeting_user_id;
        $new['project_id'] = $request->project_id;
        $new['agenda'] = $request->agenda;

        $meeting = new Meeting();
        $meeting->persist($new);
        return back()->with('success', 'Meeting Created Successfully!');
    }
}

public function edit_meeting($id)
{
    $customers = Customer::all();
    $projects = Project::all();
    $meeting = Meeting::find($id);
    return view('admin.meeting.add-meeting', get_defined_vars());
}
```

Here is `add-meeting.blade.php` file:

```
                <form action="{{url('admin/update-meeting')}}" method="POST" id="add-rel-form"
                      enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    @csrf

                    @if(isset($meeting))
                        <input class="hidden" type="hidden" name="id" value="{{$meeting->id ?? ''}}">
                    @endif
                    <div class="form-row">
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6 mb-0">
                            <label> Meeting Schedule</label>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="datetime-local" value="{{$meeting->meeting_scedule ?? ''}}" required
                                       class="form-control" name="meeting_scedule" id="meeting_scedule">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group col-md-6 mb-0">
                            <label> User</label>
                            <select id="customer-select" class='form-control' required name="meeting_user_id">
                                <option value="" id="">--Select User--</option>
                                @foreach($customers as $customer)
                                    <option value="{{$customer->id}}"{{ $customer->id == $meeting->meeting_user_id ? 'selected' : '' }}>{{$customer->first_name." ".$customer->last_name}}</option>
                                @endforeach
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-row">
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6 mb-0">
                            <label> Project</label>
                            <select id="project-select" class='form-control' required name="project_id" disabled>
                                <option value="" id="">--Select Project--</option>
                                @foreach($projects as $project)
                                    <option value="{{$project->id}}"{{$project->id == $meeting->project_id ? 'selected' : ''}}>{{$project->project_type}}</option>
                                @endforeach
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6 mb-0">
                            <label> Agenda</label>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <textarea type="text" value="" required
                                          class="form-control" name="agenda" id="agenda">{{$meeting->agenda ?? ''}}</textarea>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck?

Comment: I would assume that you haven't defined the variable, as the error message tells you. Have a look at `add_meeting()` for this

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no `$meeting` variable when creating a new meeting, the error occurs.

You can use [null coalescing operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) (`??`) or ternary operator (`?:`) to check if `$meeting` is defined before attempting to access its properties :

```
@if(isset($meeting))
    <input class="hidden" type="hidden" name="id" value="{{$meeting->id}}">
@endif

...

<select id="customer-select" class='form-control' required name="meeting_user_id">
    <option value="" id="">--Select User--</option>
    @foreach($customers as $customer)
        <option value="{{$customer->id}}" {{ isset($meeting) && $customer->id == $meeting->meeting_user_id ? 'selected' : '' }}>{{$customer->first_name." ".$customer->last_name}}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>

...

<select id="project-select" class='form-control' required name="project_id" disabled>
    <option value="" id="">--Select Project--</option>
    @foreach($projects as $project)
        <option value="{{$project->id}}"{{ isset($meeting) && $project->id == $meeting->project_id ? 'selected' : ''}}>{{$project->project_type}}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>

...

<textarea type="text" value="" required class="form-control" name="agenda" id="agenda">{{ isset($meeting) ? $meeting->agenda : '' }}</textarea>
```